# Get all search results from page in R

Tags: r

I was hoping to extract all seach results from the following URL using rvest and selector gadget

https://www.carzone.ie/used-cars/toyota/c-hr

There are 132 results I would like returned

```
url <- "https://www.carzone.ie/used-cars/toyota/c-hr"
     

url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("t-plum") %>% 
    html_attr('href')
```

this returns "character(0)"

Running as far as html_nodes("t-plum") returns {xml_nodeset (0)}

Thanks

Comment: If you run only up to `read_html()` you'll see the next set of nodes you can select. Looks like `head` and `body` are your options. From there it looks pretty difficult to find the search results.

Comment: `{xml_nodeset (0)}` indicates no matches were found for `t-plum`. What exactly are the results you're trying to get? Is it a link to every car listed on the page?

Comment: Yes that's right, every link to a car